# Texture Painting Issue in Blender Rendered Mode ..?

Tags: rendering

I am working on texture painting in Blender.

After performing UV mapping, I saved the file by going to 'file - export - wavefront(.obj)'. Then, I loaded the saved file into Procreate for coloring. After that, I saved only the PNG file separately and added it back to the 'image texture node' in the shading tab.

For some minor adjustments, I went back into texture paint mode to apply color. However, in 'Viewport shading Rendered' mode, it doesn't display. It does display in 'Viewport shading Material Preview' and 'Viewport shading Solid' modes.

The file is in the same directory as the Blender project.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: it should refresh after you've switched to the other mode, maybe pack your image and share your file?